# Simple conditional statement and parse order problem

Tags: ee2, conditionals, channel-form

I'm fairly new to ExpressionEngine, and I hope the problem I'm running into is a simple one to solve. I'll try to illustrate it as best as possible:

I have a radio button field (created within a channel form) called `favorite_food`. It has 4 options, namely `Pasta`, `Vegetables`, `Poultry`, and `Fruit`. The form displays great, and submitted values are saved in the channel entries.

The problem comes in when I'm trying to display the results on another template, and specifically adding a conditional statement that checks if the user selected `Fruit` or not is causing me to go a little crazy. This is what I've tried:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="foods" entry_id="{segment_4}"}

    <!-- displays "Fruit" successfully -->
    <div>{favorite_food}</div> (displays Fruit on the screen)

    <!-- this does not display anything at all? -->
    {if favorite_food == "Fruit"}
        <div>You chose fruit!</div>
    {/if}

    <!-- even with PHP, this works great... -->
    <?php echo "{favorite_food}"; ?>

    <!-- ...but this also doesn't display anything at all? -->
    <?php
        if ("{favorite_food}" == "Fruit")
            echo "<div>You chose fruit!</div>";
    ?>

{/exp:channel:form}
```

I should mention that the PHP parsing is set to "input" on this template too. I hope I'm missing something really obvious here...thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2):

The radio field might need to be parsed like:

```
{if "{favorite_food}" == "Fruit"}
    <div>You chose fruit!</div>
{/if}
```

which makes it an advanced conditional (parsed later in [parse order](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html)).

For [php on input](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/php.html), the php is run before the ee tags get parsed. So when the template is parsed after the php was run your php statements would look like:

```
<!-- even with PHP, this works great... -->
{favorite_food}

<!-- ...but this also doesn't display anything at all? -->
```

So the first works. The second doesn't output anything (other than the comment) because {favorite_food} is evaluated as a string only instead of as an ee variable, and so as a conditional it's false. If on the other hand you had php set on output, the first would still work and the second should as well.